# My code is giving an error which I am not able to understand

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

**I know that this question has been asked on SO before, but I am trying to find what's wrong with my code.**
I am supposed to print the longest substring in alphabetical order.
Here is my code in Python 2.7
https://ideone.com/SXQGdd

```
s='abc'
b=[]
count=1
j=0
for i in range(0,len(s)-2):
 if(s[i]<=s[i+1]):
  count=count+1
  if(i==(len(s)-2)):
    x=s[j:(j+count)]
    b.append(x)
    break

  if(s[i]>s[i+1]):
    x=s[j:(j+count)]
    b.append(x)
    continue



max_length=len(b[0])
elem=b[0]
for i in range(0,len(b)-1):
    if(len(b[i+1])>max_length):
        max_length=len(b[i+1])
        elem=b[i+1]


print"Longest substring in alphabetical order is:",elem
```

Here is the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

1. What's exactly wrong with the code?
2. Also, is there any logical error in the algorithm(I mean will the code find the longest substring in alphabetical order for any other string, s)?

Comment: `b[ len(b) ]` might throw IndexError -> `len(b[i+1])`

Comment: @luoluo that is for improving `functioning`code

Comment: @luolou This code doesn't work, which puts it off-topic for [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @luoluo You're completely wrong. Please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: IndexError is raised in line 20: `len(b[0])` because `b` is empty because `if i == len(s)-2` is never true because `range` does not include the endpoint.

Comment: And by the way, finding the longest string is as easy as `elem = max(b, key=len)` ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***IndexError*** is raised in line `20: len(b[0])` because b is empty because if `i == len(s)-2` is never true because range does not include the endpoint. Ref @swenzel

In your first for loop, your logic don,t occur correctly and getting over index value. That's why you get error message.

I just change your first loop. So, You can try this. It's ok

```
s='abc'
b=[]
store = 0
for i in range(0,len(s)):
    sub_value = s[i]
    if store == len(s)-1:
        break
    elif i == store:
        while store+1 <len(s) and s[store] <= s[store+1]:
            store += 1
            sub_value += s[store]
    b.append(sub_value)

print b
max_length= len(b[0])
elem = b[0]
for i in range(0,len(b)-1):
    if(len(b[i+1])>max_length):
        max_length=len(b[i+1])
        elem = b[i+1]

print"Longest substring in alphabetical order is:",elem
```

Output:

```
Longest substring in alphabetical order is: abc
```

Comment: Your implementation doesn't need `count` anymore, so you can get rid of it... also be careful when overwriting a value of a for-each loop. `b` will contain `['abc','bc','c']` because, despite your nested while loop, `i` will still be set to 0, 1 and 2! ;)

Comment: @swenzel Yes, you correct. I updated now my answer. please take a look